# How to make jquery animation functions run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate the Bootstrap modal windows opening effect, combining `fadeIn()` and `animate()` functions. However, jQuery executes these functions in sequence, not in parallel, so the result is that the div appears and then translates.

This is the code:

```
    $('div')
       .delay(1000)
       .fadeIn(500)
       .animate({top: 40}, 500)
       .queue(function(a) { 
          a(); 
       });
```

How can I obtain a fade in and translate effect simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: You can achieve the same result in css...

Comment: Yeah, I know. My question is if it's possible with jQuery

Comment: just do it wthout chainning

Comment: @MisterJojo can you ad example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping the element in two separate divs. let the fadeIn effect be the parent div.

Comment: Can you do an example?

Comment: <div class="for-fade-effect">
<div class="for-animaton-effect">.....................</div>
</div>


$('.for-fade-effect').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
$('.for-animaton-effect').animate({top: 40}, 500)

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you!
Ps: delay must be even in the second script, like this:

$('#one').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
$('#two').delay(1000).animate({Top: 40}, 500);